# Create ios Adhoc app and install it, but can't open it. (Click and open it, then just stoped)

Tags: ios, swift

Create ios Adhoc app and install it, but can't open it. (Click and open it, then just stoped)

- install into ios 14.5, it was working well
- install into ios 13.4 and below, can't open it

Build Settings: deployment target: on ios 9.0.

Comment: Can't get any log, to find out what is wrong with it .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device UDID is added into developer account

Get the UDID from iTunes:

https://www.innerfence.com/howto/find-iphone-unique-device-identifier-udid

1. Login to your iphone provisioning portal through developer.apple.com
2. Add the UDID in devices.
3. Add the device to the provisioning profile.
4. Download the profile again and enjoy.